# Minify javascript library from latest repository commit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple frontend example of machine learning using [ml5.js](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library), my problem is that one of the key feature I need has been merged to the master branch only five days ago and has not been added to the released min.js linked in the readme.md.

I was wondering if it was possible to build myself a minified version of the library using the code from the latest commit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try checking it out from git and running the build script?

Comment: Or you could also just use something like this in your project: https://www.minifier.org/. There are probably a number of ways to integrate that into whatever is powering your build process. Would you consider adding some more information about your development environment? That might help us answer the question more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I was just missing some instruction from the CONTRIBUTION.md

It was just a matter of cloning the repository and then run npm install & run